# How can I select only common properties from a results set?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Lets say I have a table with columns such as:

- `ID`
- `Name`
- `City`
- `State`
- `ZIP`

I need to write a query that will return only one row. This row will include `City`, `State`, and `ZIP`, but I only want a field to have a value if all values in the results set are the same, otherwise I want the field to be `null`.

For example, if every record has the same State, then State would be in the result returned. If *just one* of the results has a different state, I want the field to be `null`. Is something like this possible in SQL Server 2005?

Basically, I want a query like this:

```
SELECT City, State, ZIP
FROM Users
WHERE ID IN(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

But only return a single row, with the specs I described above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT city) = 1 THEN MAX(city) ELSE NULL END AS city,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT state) = 1 THEN MAX(state) ELSE NULL END AS state,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT zip) = 1 THEN MAX(zip) ELSE NULL END AS zip
FROM Users
WHERE ID IN(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

After other answer:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT NULLIF(city,'**NULL**')) = 1 THEN MAX(city) ELSE NULL END AS city,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT NULLIF(state,'**NULL**')) = 1 THEN MAX(state) ELSE NULL END AS state,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT NULLIF(zip,'**NULL**')) = 1 THEN MAX(zip) ELSE NULL END AS zip
FROM Users
WHERE ID IN(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

Comment: to make this solution completely safe, you need to use a check constraint to make sure that **NULL** cannot be saved in any of involved columns

Comment: Good point. I only used **NULL** for emphasis, but I'd still need it for empty string.

Answer (score 2):

If columns are not nullable, or if you want to ignore nulls then gbn's answer is correct. If, however, you need to treat null values as different values, try this:

```
CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT city) = 1 
      AND COUNT(city) = COUNT(*) 
     THEN MAX(city) ELSE NULL END AS city
```

Comment: I completely forgot about NULLs. I do want to treat Nulls differently. This is a big help. Thanks.